# Is object eligible for garbage collection if it's created within using-statement and not explicitly bound to a reference?

Tags: c#, .net, using-statement

I have this (illustration only) C# code:

```
using( new System.IO.MemoryStream() ) {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Note that here a `MemoryStream` is created and not explicitly bound to a reference. So unless there's some special treatment because of the `using` statement the object has no references to it and could be collected before control leaves the `using` statement and maybe even before `Sleep()` completes.

Is `MemoryStream` eligible for collection before control leaves the `using` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is NOT.

Behind the scenes, a hidden reference to the `MemoryStream` has been created, so it is still alive.

Comment: "Behind the scenes" in this case means the compiler output for the `using` statement, which roughly approximates a `try-finally` block. `using` is the same as `foreach` in that the keyword instructs the compiler to generate code that actually does the legwork in the background, that code is then compiled into IL.

Answer (score 8):

No.

The `using` statement compiles to a `finally` block that disposes the object.

Thus, it is still in scope until the end of the block.